# how to connect to the django testing database correctly?

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I have a problem with django testing database.

I use setUp method like this:

```
def setUp(self):
    super().setUp()
    self.obj1 = MyModel.objects.create(name="name1")
    self.obj2 = MyModel.objects.create(name="name2")
    self.obj3 = MyModel.objects.create(name="name3")
```

But when I try to connect to testing database:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

db_uri = settings.DB_URI.replace("/db_name", "/test_db_name")
con = psycopg2.connect(db_uri)
cur = con.cursor()
```

and execute:

```
query = sql.SQL(
    "select * from {table};"
).format(
    table=sql.Identifier("mymodel_table_name"),
)
cur.execute(query)

print('result', cur.fetchall())
```

In result I see the empty list.

BUT!
If I insert something in testing database:

```
query = sql.SQL(
    "insert into {table} (id, name) values ({id}, {name});"
).format(
    table=sql.Identifier("mymodel_table_name"),
    id=sql.Literal(some_id),
    name=sql.Literal(some_name),
)
cur.execute(query)
```

I see it in ORM, when I execute:

```
MyModel.objects.all()
```

My purpose is get in `test_db_name` all objects, which I insert in setUp method.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: It looks like you are inserting the data in production database and not in the test database. that is why ORM is able to print the values, can you try to login to psql using pgadmin and verify the contents of both production and test database ?

Comment: @JayantSeth Sorry, I forgot to make it clear: I execute MyModel.objects.all() inside the TestCase.

Comment: Even in that case it might still be using production database, can you please use pgadmin or psql shell to verify the contents of production and test database.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same issue, turned out that I needed to use [TransactionTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase) instead of TestCase.

> TransactionTestCase and TestCase are identical except for the manner
> in which the database is reset to a known state and the ability for
> test code to test the effects of commit and rollback:
>
> - A TransactionTestCase resets the database after the test runs by truncating all tables. A TransactionTestCase may call commit and
>   rollback and observe the effects of these calls on the database.
> - A TestCase, on the other hand, does not truncate tables after a test. Instead, it encloses the test code in a database transaction
>   that is rolled back at the end of the test. This guarantees that the
>   rollback at the end of the test restores the database to its initial
>   state.